# googlefinance function on google sheets stopped working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

I have a google sheet that I use to monitor my forex trades. in it I use the googlefinance function to retrieve the latest forex quotes.

And it did work fine until very few days ago, now I'm getting an error:

```
Errore
Durante la valutazione di GOOGLEFINANCE, 
la query per il simbolo "AUDCAD" 
non ha restituito dati.
```

(in english would something like: "Error while evaluating GOOGLEFINANCE, query for symbol AUDCAD didn't return any data")

The function that worked until few days ago was:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:AUDCAD")
```

now it seems to briefly work with:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("AUDCAD")
```

shows the price for a moment, but then turns back to N/A.

I'm not sure what could have changed there but I could not find any notice that things might be changing.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out from [the function docs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en) that this function has mechanisms in place to prevent harvesting the data.

In my document I had a sheet containing all the quotes, then another sheet doing a lookup and finding the right price for the currency pair.

It was all fine while my lookup was within a more complex formula, then I thought of proxying the quotes, and this triggered the protection.

From the way it works I think that using the `googlefinance` function actually caches data, so having copies doesn't actually retrieve the data multiple times.

so I removed the lookup, and just copied the `googlefinance` function everywhere where it was relevant.

Answer (score 0):

you can build contra measurment like this:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(
 GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:AUDCAD");
 GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:AUDCAD"));
 GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:AUDCAD"))
```